# Replace rude words for asterisks and have the number of asterisks match the number of letters in the rude words

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have the following code which is working to filter out rude words from a string and replace them with askerisks however I would like the number of askerisks to equal the number of letters in the rude word. For example if the word 'ass' was censored then it would be replaced with three askerisks. How do I modify this code to achieve this? Thanks.

```
$naughtyWords = array("ahole","anus","ash0le","ash0les","asholes","ass"); //etc

foreach ($naughtyWords as &$word) {
    $word = ' '.$word.' ';
}

$string = str_replace($naughtyWords, " **** ", ' '.$string.' ');
```

Comment: That's going to give you more trouble than it's worth: consider `I love cl***ical music`

Comment: Hello no it would leave classical music alone as it only matches the word if a space exists before and after the word.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$naughty_words = array('ahole', 'anus', 'ash0le', 'ash0les', 'asholes', 'ass');
$string = 'classical music ass dirty ass. molass';

foreach ($naughty_words as $naughty_word) {
    $string = preg_replace_callback('#\b' . $naughty_word . '\b#i', function($naughty_word) {return str_repeat('*', strlen($naughty_word[0]));}, $string);
}
```

Comment: But this will catch e.g. `classical music`

Comment: Fixed with a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$naughtyWords = array("ahole","anus","ash0le","ash0les","asholes","ass"); //etc

foreach ($naughtyWords as $word) {
    $replacement = str_repeat('*', strlen($word));
    $string = str_replace(' '.$word.' ', $replacement, $string);
}
```

Comment: But this will catch e.g. `classical music`