# Replace word with stars (exact length)

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

am trying to replace a word in a string BUT i want to get the word found in the function and replace it with a word with stars with the exact length ?

Is this possible or do i need to do this in some other way ?

```
$text = "Hello world, its 2018";
$words = ['world', 'its'];


echo str_replace($words, str_repeat("*", count(FOUND) ), $text);
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to replace `world` (5 letters) to `*****` (5 stars), and `its` to `***` (3 stars)?

Comment: @Zoric Are you using this technique to hide profane text? or make usernames anonymous?  There are more considerations to implement in this task.  What is your expected result when `$text = "Science: Questions that may never be answered; Religion: Answers that can never be questioned";` and `$words = ['question', 'answer'];` ?

Comment: @mickmackusa im using this to censor words in comments

Comment: Please express your expected result from my sample input.  How will you handle words like "assassinate"?  If you are happy to ignore word boundaries then you should not be using regex.

Comment: @mickmackusa i already have a working code i got from Syscall that i modified

Comment: I know.  I am here to tell you that you have selected a less efficient method.  Regex is overkill / not necessary -- and I LOVE regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad Word Filter, how do I replace words by their length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111417/bad-word-filter-how-do-i-replace-words-by-their-length)

Comment: Your task is an impossible rabbit hole. Related reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134344/how-to-replace-bad-words-in-a-comment-with-asterisks-using-php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351532/how-to-remove-offensive-words-from-post-by-php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853069/replace-rude-words-for-asterisks-and-have-the-number-of-asterisks-match-the-numb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to do that :

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('~(?:'.implode('|',$words).')~i', function($matches){
    return str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[0]));
}, $text);
echo $text ; // "Hello *****, *** 2018"
```

You also could secure this using `preg_quote` before to use `preg_replace_callback()` :

```
 $words = array_map('preg_quote', $words);
```

---

**EDIT :** The following code is another way, that use a `foreach()` loop, but prevent unwanted behaviors (replacing part of words), and allows multi-bytes characters:

```
$words = ['foo', 'bar', 'bôz', 'notfound'];
$text = "Bar&foo; bAr notfoo, bôzo bôz :Bar! (foo), notFOO and NotBar or 'bar' foo";
$expt = "***&***; *** notfoo, bôzo *** :***! (***), notFOO and NotBar or '***' ***";

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $text = preg_replace_callback("~\b$word\b~i", function($matches) use ($word) {
        return str_ireplace($word, str_repeat('*', mb_strlen($word)), $matches[0]);
    }, $text);
}

echo $text, PHP_EOL, $expt ;
```

Comment: I'd like to share my insight with you.  Consider this hypothetical string: `The fisherman's wife, Cassy, assumed her husband would assassinate a bucket full of bass.` and we will seek to replace `ass`.  Because you are not caching the replacement string for `ass` (`***`), your method is calling `strlen()` and `str_replace ()` on every matching occurrence.  The other answers that cache the replacement(s) only call the pair of functions once per needle.  All answers on this page should be using case-insensitivity for maximum inclusion.  Regex is not necessary for this task.

Comment: That said, if you have a bad-word dictionary of 12,000 words, then pre-determining the replacement string would be crazily expensive.  I suppose the sweet spot might be to take the time to build a bloated dictionary array with badwords as keys and hardcoded repeated asterisks as values.  This means a savings of processing time, with a cost of memory.

Comment: I should clarify by "pre-determining" I mean: iterating all bad words and generating/storing their length-specific replacement strings.

Comment: @mickmackusa Absolutely right. Thank you very much for these wise comments. What do you recommend to improve this Stack Overflow page? Do I have to edit my post by adding a more efficient answer?

Comment: Well, as I said a more efficient answer will not use regex.  Here are some variations I was toying with (without departing too much from the OP's method): https://3v4l.org/NtWIV The over-arching truth is: people will circumvent the bad-word list no matter how much time you spend on it.  They'll use symbols and spaces and all manner of unicode and such -- that's why I call it a rabbit hole.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you for the edit. That said, Stack Overflow [says](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) : _"Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked."_

Comment: Not imploding to generate a single God pattern will mean that you are forcing a `preg_replace_call()` as you iterate every word.   This mean means scanning the sentence _n_ times for a single word (in 3 different forms); this seems expensive.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason not to use `\b`, I'd recommend using word boundaries to avoid alternations  (`|`).

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for your reply/review. I've updated the answer to use `\b`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
$text = "Hello world, its 2018";
$words = ['world', 'its'];

// Loop through your word array
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $length = strlen($word);                    // length of the word you want to replace
    $star   = str_repeat("*", $length);         // I build the new string ****
    $text   = str_replace($word, $star, $text); // I replace the $word by the new string
}

echo $text; // Hello *****, *** 2018
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Another approach:

```
$text = "Hello world, its 2018";
$words = ['world', 'its'];

$f = function($value) { return str_repeat("*", strlen($value)) ; } ;
$replacement = array_map($f, $words);
echo str_replace($words, $replacement, $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go like this..

```
$text = "Hello crazy world, its 2018";
$words = ['world', 'its'];

array_walk($words,"replace_me");

function replace_me($value,$key)
{
    global $text;
    $text = str_replace($value,str_repeat("*",strlen($value)),$text);
}

echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$text = "Hello world, its 2018";
$words = ['world', 'its'];

// Loop through your word array
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $length = strlen($word);                    // length of the word you want to replace
    $star   = str_repeat("*", $length);         // I build the new string ****
    $text   = str_replace($word, $star, $text); // I replace the $word by the new string
}

echo $text; // Hello *****, *** 2018
```